# Is it possible to start apache2 as non-service foreground program?

Tags: apache2, service

apache2 normally runs a service. I don't apache2 service to run in background. I want to run it as long as it's a foreground program so I know that when I close my terminals while forgetting to stop a background service.

If not, is there any simple alternative? `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` is perfect except it doesn't support POST unless I write a script.

So I am trying to find a single command server program that doesn't run as service.

Answer (score 3):

The command you search for is something like:

```
httpd -D FOREGROUND -e debug
```

But be aware this can have challenges with performance.

Comment: From what I know httpd is same as apache2. `apache2 -D FOREGROUND -e debug`
gave me `[core:warn] [pid 1038] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot`.
If not, how to install httpd.

Comment: @Anutrix, did you configure your server?

Comment: `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000` was just simple.

Comment: @Anutrix that error just means you didnt preload the envvars file or whatever one you have with system variables used in the configuration of your apache server.

Comment: Does starting it as a service not require that conf? Oddly, I get no errors when starting it as a service.

Comment: @Anutrix, did you check what variables are set in service script?

Answer (score 0):

`php -S 0.0.0.0:8000` was the simplest way(short command) to host a temporary server that supports POST by default that I could find.

Src: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33213/306145